# How can I convert Int64 column in float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this question:
https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding-question?id=9900&python=1
and aI need to return the result 'salary' in float, but `.astype(float)` don't work

my code:

```
# Import your libraries
import pandas as pd

# Start writing code
result = employee.groupby(['department'])['salary'].sum().reset_index()
result['salary'] = result['salary']
result['salary'] = result['salary'].astype(float)
result
```

I tried use this: `result['salary'] = pd.to_numeric(result['salary'], downcast='float')`
but the result is the same:
[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kAhS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the reason that astype(float) method doesn't work for you, but maybe try the to_numeric method:

```
result['salary'] = pd.to_numeric(result['salary'], downcast='float')
```

Comment: I edited the question with the code you added

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
result['salary'] = result['salary'] / 1.0
```

Comment: the result was the same